# How can I order by multiple columns using the IQueryable in Cosmos DB?

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How can I order by multiple columns using the IQueryable in Cosmos DB?

I tried to do the following:

`books.OrderBy(book => book.Author).ThenBy(book => book.Name);`

and it works on the Cosmos DB simulator, but it does not work on a real DB. Why?

Here is the error I am getting:

`The order by query does not have a corresponding composite index that it can be served from.`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? the query looks fine? what is the source and what is the expected result?

Comment: @SebastianSiemens, I am trying to sort by one column and then if the first column values are the same by the second column. Where can I find logs for the Cosmos DB errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an issue with your C# code. If you want to use `ORDER BY` on a property that property needs to be indexed. For multiple columns it's the same although you need a composite index for all the properties that appear in your `ORDER BY` clause in the exact same order.

For your use case you would need the following index added to your Cosmos DB container:

```
"compositeIndexes": [
    [
        {
            "path": "/Author",
            "order": "ascending"
        },
        {
            "path": "/Name",
            "order": "ascending"
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: Also, I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-manage-indexing-policy) documentation useful. Because, in my case I am not allowed to edit the production database directly, but have to write a migration using SDK.